# bash: operations on folder according to the pattern of its name

Tags: bash

I am dealing with the selection of particular folders located within directory contained many folders with the name in the following syntax:
prot_cne_ligNNN (where NNN is the digit from 1 to 1000)

I need a bash script which will select folders of the selected numbers (gived in NNN) and then copy it to another folder

```
# define the list on numbers, which directories will be coppied
# meaning that I need to take a directory prot_cne_lig331, prot_cne_lig767, prot_cne_lig998
list=['331','767','998']
for system in ${somewhere}/*
system_name=$(basename "$system")
   if system_name == '*one_of_the_element_from_the_list*'
   cp $system $desired_output_folder
   fi
done
```

so here I need to define accurately IF statement suitable to check whether folder name contain one of the number mentioned in the list

Answer (score 1):

It seems it would be easier to iterate over your list than to iterate over all the names in the directory and test each against the list.

```bsh
list=( 331 767 998 )

for number in "${list[@]}"; do
    cp -r "$somewhere/prot_cne_lig$number" "$destdir"
done
```

Note the syntax for defining an array in `bash`.

Or, without the separate array variable,

```bsh
for number in 331 767 998; do
    cp -r "$somewhere/prot_cne_lig$number" "$destdir"
done
```

Alternatively, you could use

```bsh
shopt -s extglob
cp -r "$somewhere"/prot_cne_lig@(331|767|998) "$destdir"
```

where `@(331|767|998)` is an extended globbing pattern (hence `shopt -s extglob`) that would match the patterns in the parenthesis.

Comment: thank you so much! could you tell me whether it would be possible to use the second possibility (with glob) but not defining precisely the name of the folder in the cp statement like cp ${somewhere}/*lig@(331|767|998) ${analys}   meaning that I need all of the folders ended with lig331, lig767 and lig998 regardless of their full names

Comment: BTW, I've just checked all possibilities: with the array it works OK but very slowly (for hundreds of folders),  while with glob it does not work at all !